# How do I permanently install an apt package in Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I tried to install a package with `apt-get` cloud shell once but the next day it was gone. I saw another stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359043/customizing-the-cloud-environment-to-include-a-package-permanently). But it was out of date (I think). Please help.

Comment: See: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/configuring-cloud-shell#environment_customization_script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the link @DazWilkin has provided, the only directory where Cloud Shell persists your file is at `$HOME` directory. Anything installed with `apt` will not persist when the instance provisioned in Cloud Shell shuts down.

There's a solution for this problem. The script `$HOME/.customize_environment` runs everytime you boot up Cloud Shell. It is already running as root and there you can run `apt` to install the packages you want.

Example, as per doc:

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get update
apt-get -y install erlang
```

**Update**: There seems to be an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66480134/google-cloud-shell-customize-environment-not-working) where `.customize_environment` is not working. It's been confirmed by a Google Engineer and it's currently being fixed.

Comment: So that is why `.coustomize_enviroment` isn't working

Comment: But is there a way to install an apt package to `$HOME`?

Comment: I can only see workarounds. It really depends to you if it's all worth it, but for me it isn't. https://askubuntu.com/questions/193695/installing-packages-into-local-directory

Comment: It Is **is** worth it